# How to specify my connection to neo4j as a leader role in K8s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes, neo4j, kubernetes-ingress, neo4jrb

I deployed a 3-core (by default) Neo4j in K8s via this [helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/neo4j). I'm quite a newbie to neo4j.

I'm using [neo4jrb](https://github.com/neo4jrb/activegraph) in a Ruby on Rails project.

When I tried to connect the neo4j service to write data. I often (not always) met this error

```
Neo4j::Core::CypherSession::CypherError:   Cypher error:
  Neo.ClientError.Cluster.NotALeader: No write operations are allowed directly on this database. Writes must pass through the leader. The role of this server is: FOLLOWER
```

I read this article [Querying Neo4j Clusters](https://medium.com/neo4j/querying-neo4j-clusters-7d6fde75b5b4). Then I realized there is one leader and two follower core created by the helm chart. In the cypher-shell, when I run

```
CALL dbms.cluster.overview() YIELD id, role RETURN id, role
```

I got

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id                                     | role       |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| "acce2b2c-53ae-498c-a49b-84f42897445e" | "FOLLOWER" |
| "03cabb09-de1a-40cc-b8b0-bb02981cf551" | "FOLLOWER" |
| "1aa96add-f5cd-43a1-9fc6-2a5360668bb7" | "LEADER"   |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

So I should connect to the `LEADER` when I try to write data. And I know a cluster can't be `leader` permanently. If the current `leader` is down, then the `follower` will become a new `leader`.

I once thought `bolt+routing` to a causal cluster may be an easy way to fix my issue. When I went back to the ruby client, I found it doesn't support `bolt+routing` for now.

What should I do now? I can't configure a LoadBalancer. I have access to writing a config for Ingress.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that neo4jrb supports bolt+routing.

You could try to use the java driver from graalvm's truffleruby, see:

https://github.com/michael-simons/neo4j-graalvm-polyglot-examples